# Swift Package Manager gets stuck indefinitely upon adding new package

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, swift-package-manager

I just updated Xcode to 13.2 (and MacOS Monterey) and it doesn't recognize the 3rd-party packages which I had added in Xcode 13.1 using SPM. So I removed them from the target and tried to add them anew. But it gets stuck here indefinitely:

[image]

Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: There seems to be an error with swift packages and Xcode 13.2 [if you download it from the app store](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/rg2sem/be_carefule_when_upgrading_to_xcode_132/). Instead, try downloading from the developer website.

Comment: I'm gonna try downloading from dev portal...

Comment: It's working @aheze thanks! If you want post your answer I will mark it as correct.